# ArcGIS for Mac OS X

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, mac, arcgis-ios

Is there a way to use ArcGIS (ArcMap) on a Mac Operating, without running Parallels/Boot Camp or anything that allows you to run Windows on the Mac

Comment: ArcGIS does not run on Mac OSX. Have you looked at this?: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm

Comment: No. The closest approach is no longer possible due to DirectX compatibility. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/run-pro-on-a-mac.htm

Comment: Thanks, both answered my question. I did check the requirements, but just wondered if there was a way around it. Seems running parallels is the best option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Aaron and @Vince said in the comments, no ArcGIS does not run on Mac OS X without some variation of Parallels/BootCamp.

For further details see the link that @Aaron shared about [current system requirements for ArcGIS Desktop (10.7.x)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/system-requirements/latest/arcgis-desktop-system-requirements.htm) or the link that @Vince shared to [Run ArcGIS Pro on a Mac](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/run-pro-on-a-mac.htm).

Comment: Probably best to quote the relevant text, in case the links change.